# A Work-Kinetic energy proof that is mathematically sound?

Tags: physics, line-integrals

I was looking at proofs of $W=\Delta \text{KE}$ along curves online and they all seem sloppy to me. I'm wondering if this specific proof is mathematically sound, or if anyone has seen a mathematically sound proof:

---

Let $v=\frac{dr}{dt}$ denote the velocity vector, as let $r$ denote the position vector. Let $F=m\frac{dv}{dt}$ denote the force at a specified position. Let the mass $m$ be constant. Then the work done along a curve $C$ is defined as,

$$W=\int_{C} F \cdot dr=m \int_{C} \frac{dv}{dt} \cdot dr$$

---

The next steps seem sloppy to me.

$$=m \int_{v_i}^{v_f} \frac{dr}{dt} \cdot dv$$

$$=m \int_{v_i}^{v_f} v \cdot dv$$

$$=m \int_{|v_i|}^{|v_f|} |v| \,d|v|$$

$$=\frac{1}{2}m|v_f|^2-\frac{1}{2}m|v_i|^2$$

$$=\Delta \text{KE}$$

---

Three things seems weird to me: The treating of differential vectors as if they were just vectors, and the limits of the integration as we change variables of integration. Also even so, assuming we can treat them as vectors, how is $|dv|=d|v|$?

If it's sloppy mathematically, does anyone know how to correct it, I know for example in single variable calculus crossing out differentials can usually be made rigorous by just quoting the chain rule. What about here?

Comment: The rigorous proof I know uses the fact that $d\|v\|^2/dt = d(v\cdot v)/dt = 2v\cdot(dv/dt)$.

Comment: It's actually still the chain rule here, or you can recast it in a form which makes it more obvious right from Newton's second law $\frac{dv}{dt}= \frac{dv}{dr} \frac{dr}{dt}$ then you can perform that "cancellation" of differentials. As for the magnitudes I haven't quite seen it written that way before

Comment: To say that $v\cdot dv = \left|v\right| \, \left|dv\right|$ is wrong because it neglects the cosine of the angle between them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for the physical curves $C$ with a path between $t_1$ and $t_2$ we have from the fundamental theorem of calculus that

$$\int_C\nabla f\cdot \mathrm{d}\mathbf{r}=f(\mathbf{r}(t_2))-f(\mathbf{r}(t_2))$$

and from this your desired result follows (use after change of integration variable to $\mathbf{v}$ to get kinetic energy)

EDIT:

\begin{align*}
W&=\int_C \mathbf{F}\cdot\mathrm{d}\mathbf{r} \\
&=m\int_C \mathbf{v}\cdot\mathrm{d}\mathbf{v} \\
&=m\int_C \nabla_v\left(
\frac{\mathbf{v}^2}{2}\right)\cdot\mathrm{d}\mathbf{v} \\
&=\frac{1}{2}m\mathbf{v}(t_2)^2-\frac{1}{2}m\mathbf{v}(t_1)^2 \\
&=\Delta\mathrm{KE}
\end{align*}

Comment: May you please put in more details. I know this but don't see how to apply it.

Comment: @AhmedS.Attaalla Is it okay now?

Comment: Sorry what is $\mathbf{V}^2$?

Comment: @AhmedS.Attaalla $\mathbf{v}^2=\mathbf{v}\cdot\mathbf{v}=v_x^2+v_y^2+v_z^2$. Note the gradient is over $v$ space and not $r$ space in order to apply the lemma.

Comment: Thanks I have to get familiar with those terms, do you know any references I can look at to learn about gradients over spaces please @GPhys

Comment: @AhmedS.Attaalla There is really nothing different from the usual gradient -
 I just mean we have relabelled $(x,y,z)$ with $(v_x,v_y,v_z)$ so that $\nabla_v=(\partial/\partial v_x,\partial/\partial v_y,\partial/\partial v_z)$. The operation is still the same.

Comment: Oh, I see thanks. It all makes sense now @Gphys

Answer (score 1):

The work of the **net force** (which is mathematically just stating that the equation $\mathbf{F} \circ \mathbf{c}=m\mathbf{\ddot{c}}$ holds) is given by the variation of kinectic enery, and this is just an application of the fundamental theorem of calculus and a simple computation: that of the derivative of the real function $$E:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$$ 
$$t \mapsto \frac{m}{2}\langle \mathbf{\dot{c}}(t), \mathbf{\dot{c}}(t)\rangle.$$
We have that $E'(t)=\langle m\mathbf{\ddot{c}}(t),\mathbf{\dot{c}}(t) \rangle$ (this computation does not need Newton's second law, and is mathematical only). However, the fact that $E'(t)=\langle \mathbf{F}(\mathbf{c}(t)),\mathbf{\dot{c}}(t) \rangle$ needs it.

By the fundamental theorem of calculus, we have that
\begin{align*}
E(b)-E(a)=\int_a^bE'=\int_a^b\langle \mathbf{F}(\mathbf{c}(t)),\mathbf{\dot{c}}(t)\rangle dt,
\end{align*}
and this last one is the definition of the work of $\mathbf{F}$ along $\mathbf{c}$.

Comment: What does $\langle \rangle$ mean, Vector notation?

Comment: @AhmedS.Attaalla This is notation for an inner product space. Where you see $\langle \mathbf{a},\mathbf{b}\rangle$ you can just replace it with $\mathbf{a}\cdot \mathbf{b}$.

Comment: Thanks GPhys. This answer is also very clear now. Thank you for your answer @Aloizio Macedo